# dial a number automatically in android

Tags: android

I can't figure out how to make the app dial.

I have this code:

```
public void dial(String number)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);//calling intent
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) 
    {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

but it only opens the dialer app.
i need it to dial the given number..

any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ACTION_DIAL` to `ACTION_CALL`. This will require the `CALL_PHONE` permission.